# JQuery закрытие окна

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно

Подскажите как отменить закрытие окно если кликнули именно по элементам внутри отрытого окна.
При клике по ссылке подгружаю окно

```
$(".cell").on("click", ".load-models", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("load-models")
            , html = "";
        if( ! id) return false;

        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_AJAX + "ajax/vehicle/",
            method: "POST",
            data: {id:id},
            complete: function() {
                $(this).text("reset");
            },
            statusCode: {
                200: function(message) {
                    message.models.forEach(function(cell, index){
                        html += '<li><a href="' + BASE_AJAX + 'vehicle/' + message.vehicle.url + '/' + cell.url + '/" target="_blank">' + cell.name + '</li>';
                    });
                    $('.load-models[data-load-models="' + id + '"]').after('<div class="window shadow" data-windows="true"><ul class="scrollbar-inner vehicle-models">' + html + '</ul></div>');
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('.scrollbar-inner').scrollbar({
                            disableBodyScroll: true,
                        });
                        $('.scrollbar-inner').css({ "max-height": "300px", "min-height": "300px" });
                    });
                },
                403: function(jqXHR) {
                    var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('.error').html(error.message)
                        .css({
                            display: "inline-block"
                        });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Закрываю окно так

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
    $(".window").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $( this ).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: в смысле остановить аннимацию, вернуть opacity и не выполнять .remove() ? со вторым пунктом я думаю вы сами справитесь, первый пункт - 

    $('.window').click(function(){$(this).stop();}

Comment: вообще я не советовал бы вам называть класс window  это сильно запутывает.

Comment: окей, назову по другому. спс!

Comment: Нужно ничего не делать с окном, если нажатие было внутри него. Например в окне есть кнопка button, по ней кликаю, окно закрывается, вот и нужно чтобы не закрывалось оно в таких случаях, а если кликнули не внутри блока .block, тогда окно .block закрывается.
Со .stop() сейчас буду эксперементировать =) СПС

Comment: а ну тогда 

if ($(e.target).is('.window')) return ;